# Inserting the values in separate rows using php

Tags: php

I am using a curl concept and getting the description from the other website but the  description is inserting in aldpabetic order like :

all **A's** in one row and all **B's** in one row

and so on but i want all of them to be in separate rows. Please help.

```
include('simple_html_dom.php'); // get DOM from URL or file 
$html = file_get_html('animecrunch.com/';); 
// find all td tags with attribite valign=top and plain text    
foreach($html->find('td[valign=top]') as $e) { 
   $anime= htmlentities(trim($e->plaintext), ENT_NOQUOTES ,'UTF-8'); 
   $vowels = array("!", "'"); 
   $pureanime = str_replace($vowels, "", "$anime"); 
   $count=mysql_num_rows($query1); 
   if($count==0) { 
      $query=mysql_query("insert into anime(anime) values('$pureanime')") or die(mysql_error()); 
      header("location:test1.php"); 
   }
}
```

Comment: Inserting where? Alphabetic order of what? Which other website? What rows? You need to be a little more clear...

Comment: 1)animecrunch.com is the website i am pointing using curl concept 2)In that website(animecrunch.com) the anime names are like alphabetic order and i am getting those video names to be inserted into db but all the A series are inserted in one row , B series in one row and so on... i want them to be inserted each video name in separate row

Comment: What's your code like? How can we find what's wrong if we don't have anything to see?

Comment: You are parsing the HTML wrong. Assuming that you are reading the <table> inside of #newanimeepisodesmenu2, you need to parse out all the <a> tags and run queries on them separately (or better, one query with multiple inserts). Without seeing your code, we can't really see what the problem is.

Comment: @user1387101 Can you edit your question instead of posting as a comment? It's impossible to read.

Comment: foreach($html->find('td[valign=top]') as $e)
{
        $anime= htmlentities(trim($e->plaintext), ENT_NOQUOTES ,'UTF-8');
  
  $vowels = array("!", "'");
        $pureanime = str_replace($vowels, "", "$anime");$query=mysql_query("insert into anime(anime) values('$pureanime')") or die(mysql_error());
header("location:test1.php");
}

Comment: @MathieuImbert I formatted the code in the question for him.

Comment: @user1387101 Are you trying to store the full <a> link in the database?

Comment: foreach($html->find('td[valign=top] a') as $e)    finally this has helped me thanks for everyone who guide me

Comment: @user1387101 You're welcome. Please make sure you select the answer as correct if your problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to store in the database, but your question says "Description", so I will assume you want just the name of the anime. You just were missing one thing, instead of finding the `td[valign=top]`, you want the `a` tag inside each of those `td`'s.

Also, I removed the redirect and the $query1 thing, which I wasn't sure where that came from. (Maybe checking if it already exists?)

```
include('simple_html_dom.php'); // get DOM from URL or file 
$html = file_get_html('animecrunch.com/';); 
// find all td tags with attribite valign=top and plain text    
foreach($html->find('td[valign=top] a') as $e) { 
   $anime= htmlentities(trim($e->plaintext), ENT_NOQUOTES ,'UTF-8'); 
   $vowels = array("!", "'"); 
   $pureanime = str_replace($vowels, "", "$anime"); 

   $query=mysql_query("insert into anime(anime) values('$pureanime')") or die(mysql_error()); 

   }
}
```